# Why are graph traversals faster than joins? Any lessons for normalized data in SQLs?

Tags: sql, graph, nosql

From [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CGYQFjAJ&url=http://www.manning.com/partner/Neo4J_meap_ch01.pdf&ei=f_8gUJTtMsPKrAfAwIDQAg&usg=AFQjCNE3RPzexxskQs3_oNgJU4DgvTOjHQ), a graph database is much faster performing the equivalent of a multi-table join. And second, a join-equivalent is the same speed regardless of the size of the table.

```
depth   seconds records
2         0.016 ~2,500 --mysql
3        30.267 ~125,000
4     1,543.505 ~600,000

2         0.010 ~2,500 --neo4j
3         0.168 ~110,000
4         1.359 ~600,000
```

I know that SQL uses **cartesian joins** which literally multiplies with the **size of the tables and number of hops**. And all I hear about graph databases is "first class relationship structure".

What is data structure + algorithm that gives graph databases fast traversals regardless of hops and table size?

How can I implement it in an RDBMS system? I am thinking left joins and nested queries.

Comment: A quick answer: hammers do a better job at driving nails than screwdrivers do. On the other hand, screwdrivers beat hammers hands down when it comes to screws.

Answer (score 1):

graph traversals are generally faster than joins because every node in the graph counts its neighbors and adds his count to the result. This can be optimized easily with multithreading etc.

I think you can't do this in SQL, but you could do this some (recursive) code. This can lead to a lot of queries which can hurt your performance.

So if you really want to work with graph data, you should use a graph database.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's assume that we're talking about simple queries resulting in joins with `ON` clauses that contain only equality conditions (e.g. `a JOIN b ON a.id = b.id`). I believe these are the kinds of queries mastered by graph traversals.

Joins are slower because they use binary searches to find pairs satisfying the join's `ON` clause, whereas graph traversals avoid these searches altogether. An edge in a graph database links (stores) the *memory addresses* of the nodes it connects. Similarly, a node stores the memory addresses of its edges. Want to find the nodes connected to node 1? Go to all of node 1's edges (in memory/on disk), then for each edge, just go to its other node (in memory/on disk). Voila! (Disclaimer: I don't know this for sure. I haven't looked at source code. But I have a very strong hunch).

I had an idea to emulate the speed of a graph traversal in a RDBMS using hash indexes, since equality lookups for hash indexes are O(1) (rather than O(log n) for binary search). Hopefully I'll return to this post with some test results.